# XAML errors using StaticResource from external assembly in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have a resource dictionary in an external assembly, which I have merged in my app.xaml, like so:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/My.Library;component/Theme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I wish to reference said resources using StaticResource bindings.

I am getting design-time errors in Visual Studio 2013 stating the resources do not exist.  I am not getting any compiler errors though, and the resources do show up fine at run-time.

I have read posts about problems with the VS Designer not showing external resources properly, but I don't use the Designer and that is not what my question is about.  I am getting errors in the error window stating the resources cannot be resolved, and I've got a serious case of the squigglies.  I have tried a full clean and rebuild.

Again, everything compiles and runs fine,  but this is not very convenient since I now have to sift through the error list to see what are actual errors and what is simply Visual Studio not resolving the referenced resources correctly.

For grins I did try switching to DynamicResource, and indeed the error went away. However, these resources will not be changing during the application lifetime and I do not wish to incur all of the extra overhead just to solve a problem with the IDE.

Does anybody know a proper fix for this?

Comment: You're putting a resource Dictionary into the program's resources & then trying to reference resources in it? Sorry, I think you need to use a DynamicResource reference, and I'm not sure that's gonna work, either.  I've never done anything like that myself so I don't know.

Comment: @TonyVitabile It does work, I'm just getting errors in the IDE.

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088762/avoiding-visual-studio-designer-errors-when-wpf-resource-is-defined-in-separate

Comment: @sexta13 The accepted answer for that post is to switch to DynamicResource, which I explained I didn't see as a viable solution.

Comment: and the answer that has more votes?

Comment: @sexta13 It's even worse,  it involves mocking out all resources into a custom resource dictionary that only loads at design-time and then including it on all of our views to prevent the errors. Creative, but highly impractical.

Comment: one last question, why dynamic is not a viable solution?

Comment: @sexta13 Dynamic causes the resource to be looked up every time it is accessed (potentially a lot), the purpose is for resources that might change during runtime, like a user-selectable brush color.  I don't want the performance penalty, especially just to hack around a problem with the IDE.

Comment: fair enough...i agree with you

Comment: Same problem here, this was working just fine in VS2010