# XAML Designer error when using styles from referenced assembly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a project CommonStyles.exe with different styles. My application has a reference to the CommonStyles.exe. Styles are declared in App.xaml (via `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`).
I use styles from CommonStyles.exe in my application with `StaticResource`.

The application works perfectly at runtime, but in design mode I get this error (Visual Studio 2010):

> “Provide value on ‘System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder’ threw an exception.”

This problem is solved if I include the project containing CommonStyles.exe in solution with my application.

The solution on question [Avoiding Visual Studio designer errors when WPF resource is defined in separate project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088762/avoiding-visual-studio-designer-errors-when-wpf-resource-is-defined-in-separate)
is to use `DynamicResource` rather than `StaticResource`. But in this solution Visual Studio displays the controls without styling in design mode. I need to look applying styles in design mode.
So Visual Studio in design mode can't find some styles, but in runtime can.

I try to realize this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/1111473/5152001
but in design mode I get error for some control like this:

> Cannot locate resource "SomeStyleBase"

This control use style "SomeStyle" from CommonStyles.exe. Style "SomeStyle" inherit on style "SomeStyleBase" from CommonStyles.exe. This styles are in different files.
This problem is solved if I merge this styles in one file. But this solution is not suitable for me.

So I had to include the project containing CommonStyles.exe in solution with my application until I will find better solution.

Comment: You need to look at the inner exception to see the detail of the problem

Comment: This error is in design mode (not in runtime) when I look windows xaml code. How can I look inner exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding Visual Studio designer errors when WPF resource is defined in separate project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088762/avoiding-visual-studio-designer-errors-when-wpf-resource-is-defined-in-separate)

Comment: thanks for the link but  I need to look applying styles in design mode (I edit my question)

Comment: That is the accepted answer. Have you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1111473/5152001)?

Comment: I try to realize this solution, but I get other error (I described it in my question)