# Get ResourceDictionary source from static member with design-time support

Tags: wpf, uri, resourcedictionary

My basic goal is to have a `ResourceDictionary` in a dll which I can use in another WPF project via [`ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries). But I don't want to reference the `ResourceDictionary` by hard-coding the URI in the XAML of the referencing application, I want to instead reference some static member which will provide the URI.

I have some simplified code which is "working", but only at runtime. At design-time it throws errors and I get no IntelliSense support. For this simplified example, everything is in one assembly (no separate dll).

`Dic.xaml` (the resource dictionary I want to reference):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" x:Key="BlueBrush"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`Foo` (the module to hold the static member with the URI):
(VB.NET version)

```
Public Module Foo
    '[VBTest] is the name of assembly
    Public ReadOnly Property URI As New Uri("pack://application:,,,/VBTest;component/Dic.xaml")
End Module
```

(C# version)

```
public static class Foo
{
    //[VBTest] is the name of assembly
    public static Uri URI { get; } = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/VBTest;component/Dic.xaml");
}
```

And then finally, the place in the application where I want to reference the `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VBTest">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="{x:Static local:Foo.URI}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="{StaticResource BlueBrush}"/>
</Window>
```

At design-time, I get two errors:

> `XDG0062  An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "".`
> `XDG0062  The resource "BlueBrush" could not be resolved.`

However, the project will build and run just fine. And will show the intended blue square.

The question is, how can I get this to work at design-time?

Comment: *how can I get this to work at design-time?* You most probably can't. It's a limiation of the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a thankfully easy workaround. Maybe not the prettiest, but it is elegant. I took inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1111473/5086631) to a somewhat related question.

By creating my own class inheriting from `ResourceDictionary`, I can better control the loading behavior. That sounds like it would be complicated, but really all I had to do was set `Source` as part of the constructor and everything just worked.

The below is added to the code file (*outsite* of `Module`/`static class` `Foo`):

```
Public Class StylesResourceDictionary
    Inherits ResourceDictionary

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Source = URI
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note that `Source = URI` is referencing `Foo.URI` from the question code.

And then the XAML file becomes:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VBTest">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <local:StylesResourceDictionary/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="{StaticResource BlueBrush}"/>
</Window>
```

And bam, full design-time support without hard-coding the URI into the referencing application. Control of the `ResourceDictionary` and its URI is now in the domain of the dll, and can be referenced in a (kinda) static fashion using the dedicated class.